# NopCommerce error SevenSpikes.Nop.Plugins.Core.dll' is denied

Tags: iis, nopcommerce

I got this error continually on my nopCommerce website.

`Application startup exception: 
System.Exception: Plugin 'Seven Spikes Core'. 
Access to the path 
'C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\mywebsite\Plugins\bin\SevenSpikes.Nop.Plugins.Core.dll' is denied.`

I have tried disabling overlapped recycle in the application pool and still, I still get the same error occasionally. What's the permanent fix?

I'm using nopCommerce version 4.20 version.

Comment: what is the nopCommerce version?

Comment: I just update the question with the nopcommerce version

Comment: try to remove the shadow copy code from PluginManager.cs.Don't forget to delete the Plugins/bin shadow directory after deploying the changes.you could refer this [link](https://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/topic/49851/serious-iis-application-pool-recycling-bugdesign-flaw/page/3#199596) for more detail

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because of the shadow copy of plugin which is resolved at the nopCommerce4.2. To resolve the error you need to follow below steps

1. You need to stop app_pool and the website.
2. Remove the all .dll from the plugin bin folder(your website==>Plugins==>bin)
3. At the appsetting.json(root directory of the website) change "UsePluginsShadowCopy" : 
   true to "UsePluginsShadowCopy": false
4. Start the app_pool first then website.

It should resolved the error. I faced same problem and get solution by following the above steps. You do not need to disable overlapped recycle.

Comment: This seems to work, I am only waiting to confirm that as the error occurs occasionally.

Comment: It will not happen for nopCommerce4.2

Answer (score 0):

After I copied the site folder to a new folder I gave this folder the APP-POOL permisions:
'IIS APPPOOL\My-IIS-Site-Name' then - restart IIS.